# What happens if a Http.get request in Elm receives a different type of response other than expected one?

Tags: http, elm

In Elm tutorial, [Http section](https://guide.elm-lang.org/effects/http.html), there is code sample where defines the `Cmd` for run-time to handle:

```
Http.get
      { url = "https://elm-lang.org/assets/public-opinion.txt"
      , expect = Http.expectString GotText
      }
```

So we expect server response to be text and pass the message type (`GotText`) to `Http.expectString` function so later the result would be attached to `GotText`. Here is `GotText` definition (it is of type: [Result](https://guide.elm-lang.org/error_handling/result.html)):

```
type Msg
  = GotText (Result Http.Error String)
```

So if any error happens during request, plus the expected response type, it would be captured inside `Http.Error` attached to `GotText`, otherwise a run-time error happens (which is not true in ELm). My question is what if server returns something other that text, i.e. binary? AFAIK there doesn't exist such a Http error as `bad response`, so is that type of error still embedded inside `Http.Error` in ELm?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

But there is. From the [elm/http docs on Http.Error](https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm/http/latest/Http#Error):

> `BadBody` means you got a response back with a nice status code, but
>   the body of the response was something unexpected. The String in this
>   case is a debugging message that explains what went wrong with your
>   JSON decoder or whatever.

Comment: Thanks. Didn't find that part of documentation in my search. But using `Http.Error` name as the error type is misleading.

Comment: Because it's not an error as defined by the http protocol? Yeah, I guess I don't entirely disagree, but it seems convenient to collapse expectation errors into that type rather than add another level to distinguish proper http errors from expectation errors.